# How to change track radius in Range Slider

Tags: rangeslider

I am using Range Slider (material) (https://m2.material.io/components/sliders/android)
I am using double sided Range Slider as given in above documentation. I am setting the height of the track using app: trackHeight="45dp" (just example). But this causes the track of the slider to have curved (circular) shape at left end and right end. How to change the radius of track at left and right end to make the track complete rectange? There is no property to set track Radius.

If tried changing all the parameters of the rangeSlider but the shape of the track is curved at left and right end. How to solve this?